# What font is used on this Google Design serif example?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

On a [Google Design blog article](https://design.google.com/articles/expressing-brand-in-material/), I found a comparison of a Roboto typeface sheet with a serif one. The article doesn't tell the name of this font.

[image: Google font example]

I did a bit of research and I suspect it is a variation of Baskerville, though different from the ones I find online. Can anyone tell what font it is?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 3):

Aha! The serif font in your example is [URW Baskerville](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/baskerville/urw-baskerville-t-regular/), a slight variation on the original Baskerville.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Baskerville Classico]

It looks like [Baskerville Classico Roman](http://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/baskerville-classico/roman) to me. I used identifont.com and searched by appearance, which is always a good place to start.

Comment: That looks darn close, it's sliiiightly different. The original example is a little lighter, visually, in some of it's letterforms. The eye of the lower case "e" is smaller and sits higher than Baskerville's, and the bowl of the lower case "a" has a more extreme slant. Really really close, though.

Comment: You're right, I can't believe I missed the "a," the difference is pretty clear now. Is it possible that Google took an existing Baskerville font and tweaked it just for that sheet?

Comment: Eh, there are TONS of fonts that are derivative of Baskerville out there. I think it's more likely that it's one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried the Baskerville-Classico? I uploaded it on the font search site 'what the font' and it looks like the standard version :)  https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/baskerville-classico/baskerville-classico/

Comment: [Be kind, show a preview of the font please.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/be-kind-show-a-preview-of-the-font)